# Extension of Arzela-Ascoli Theorem in $\mathbb R\;$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, arzela-ascoli

One version of *Arzela-Ascoli theorem* can be stated as follows:

> Consider a sequence of real-valued continuous functions
>   $\;\{ f_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}\;$ defined on a closed and bounded
>   interval $\;[a, b]\;$ of the real line. If this sequence is uniformly
>   bounded and equicontinuous, then there exists a subsequence $\; \{ {f_n}_k \}_{k \in \mathbb N} \;$ that converges uniformly.

I am trying to extend the theorem for sequences of real-valued functions defined on $\; \mathbb R\;$. One hint I've got , is to use a diagonal argument...but I'm not very familiar with this.

**EDIT:** I need to derive that a sequence of real-valued functions defined on $\; \mathbb R\;$ which satisfy the conditions of boundedness and equicontinuity on a closed interval of $\; \mathbb R\;$, has a uniformly convergent subsequence on compact intervals.

How do I proceed?

I would appreciate if somebody could enlighten me about this. Any help would be valuable!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It can't be true as stated for $\mathbb{R}$.  Take $f$ to be, say, continuous and compactly supported (and not the zero function), and set $f_n(x) = f(x-n)$.  Then $f_n$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, but no subsequence converges uniformly.

Comment: You will get _locally_ uniform convergence.

Comment: @NateEldredge What assumptions should 've been added then? I need to derive a result similar to Arzela-Ascoli for $\;\mathbb R\;$

Comment: I think only you can say what "similar" means for you.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NateEldredge I just edited my original post. I hope to be more specific this time..

Comment: @NateEldredge i'm sorry.. When I first posted this , I thought this question was different. But now I see I asked the same thing. Thank you for pointing it out. I'll check the answer on the suggested link.